# In custom AMI sshd is not getting started

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, connectivity, amazon-ami

I created my own AMI & when I start my instance sshd is not getting started. What might be the problem?

Please find below the system log snippet

```
init: rcS main process (199) terminated with status 1

Entering non-interactive startup
NET: Registered protocol family 10
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Bringing up loopback interface: OK 

Bringing up interface eth0: 
Determining IP information for eth0...type=1400 audit(1337940238.646:4): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=637 comm="dhclient-script" path="/etc/sysconfig/network" dev=xvde1 ino=136359 scontext=system_u:system_r:dhcpc_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 tclass=file
martian source 255.255.255.255 from 169.254.1.0, on dev eth0
ll header: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:08:00
type=1400 audit(1337940239.023:5): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=647 comm="dhclient-script" path="/etc/sysconfig/network" dev=xvde1 ino=136359 scontext=system_u:system_r:dhcpc_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 tclass=file
type=1400 audit(1337940239.515:6): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=674 comm="dhclient-script" path="/etc/sysconfig/network" dev=xvde1 ino=136359 scontext=system_u:system_r:dhcpc_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 tclass=file
type=1400 audit(1337940239.560:7): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=690 comm="dhclient-script" path="/etc/sysconfig/network" dev=xvde1 ino=136359 scontext=system_u:system_r:dhcpc_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 tclass=file
done.
OK 

Starting auditd: OK 

Starting system logger: OK 

Starting system message bus: OK 

Retrigger failed udev events OK 

Starting sshd: FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to selinux. Once I disabled selinux during boot up by providing selinux=0 as argument in GRUB for kernel field, the machine booted with sshd service started and I'm able to connect to it.